# ¿Cómo pasar todos los parámetros de URL a la página que se está reescribiendo?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Intento que reescriba lo siguiente:

```
http://pagina.web/lang/action/mode/bracket?parametro1=algo&parametro2=algomas
```

hacia

```
index.cgi?action=action&lang=lang&mode=mode&bracket=bracket&siguientesparametros
```

de momento tengo:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/\\?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ?action=$2&lang=$1&mode=$3&bracket=$4&$5 [L,NC]
```

pero no funciona.

Comment: Hola Akond. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de explicar mejor la pregunta. Por qué no te funciona? Muestra lo que está devolviendo. E intenta añadir más ejemplos del comportamiento esperado. Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b concuerdo, y normalmente no respondería hasta que el autor aclare... El tema con el .htaccess de Apache es que muchos usuarios no tienen acceso al log, por lo que no hay una buena forma de depurar salvo con prueba y error, si termina en un error 500 o no (se pueden setear variables de entorno, pero es un poco entreverado).

Answer (score 1):

La cadena de búsqueda o *query string* -lo que está después del `?` en una URL- no forma parte del texto con el que se compara en una [RewiteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Si quisieras verificar algo de los parámetros pasados, si coinciden con un texto, o para usarlos como parte de la redirección, usarías una [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) previa.

Sin embargo, en este caso sólo se está buscando agregarle el resto los parámetros pasados. Para eso es mucho más sencillo usar el flag [`[QSA]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa). Las siglas significan *Query String Append*, y justamente agregan la cadena de búsqueda a la página a la que se está reescribiendo/redireccionando.

Quedaría:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.cgi?action=$2&lang=$1&mode=$3&bracket=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Gracias por la repuesta, pero sigue sin funcionar no entiendo porque. le paso la url http://localhost/en/wow/3v3?page=6 y no carga la función en cambio si le paso http://localhost/index.cgi?action=wow&lang=en&mode=pvp&bracket=3v3&page=5 si que funciona

Comment: Estás pasando 3 parámetros... Te faltó pasar el cuarto, `pvp` según tu ejemplo